# Express $\sqrt 3(2+\sqrt 3)$ in the form $ a + b \sqrt3 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Express $\sqrt 3(2+\sqrt 3)$ in the form  $ a + b \sqrt3 $.

I have expanded parentheses to get: $2\cdot \sqrt{3}+3$. 
How would I go from there and write it in the form mentioned above?

Comment: If any of the answers below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've already finished.

$\color{red}{2}\sqrt{3}+\color{blue}{3}$ is in the form $\color{blue}{a}+\color{red}{b}\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: THANK YOU haha I feel so stupid.  So It doesn't nessecarily have to be written out in the form a+b root 3?  Like exactly like that?

Comment: With addition the order you write something is not important as $a+b=b+a$ due to associativity. So your answer of $2\sqrt{3}+3$ is exactly the same as $3+2\sqrt{3}$ and hence it is in the form required.

Comment: @IanMiller don't you mean commutativity...?

Comment: Yeh I do. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: According to that logic, $\sqrt{3}(2+\sqrt{3})$ is already in the required form as well.